# Using scope with ng-model in md-select with ng-repeat to save and display a JSON element

Tags: angularjs, cordova, scope, angularjs-ng-model

I'm having two bug in my app development for phonegap and I'm hoping one of you might be able to help me out. I'm building a take-out app that has 3 different sections: Menu, Options and Order. In the Options page, I have multiple checkboxes and a dropdown using md-select. What I'm trying to do is that when user selects an option from the dropdown, the option is displayed in the order page. I got that working, however, I get an additional "undefined" text that I don't need and want to get rid of.

Here's my relevant script I'm using for this (lines 278-281 in index.html in plunker):

```
  $scope.selecteds = {};
  angular.forEach($scope.items, function(value) {
  $scope.selecteds = value;
  });
```

Now, $scope.items is pre-loaded as an array of items.

```
    $scope.items = {
  "results": [{
    "active": false,
    "createdAt": "2015-10-05T20:19:58.264Z",
    "desc": "With arugula, smoked almonds \u0026 chipotle vinaigrette",
    "img": "https://signsrestaurant.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Watermelon-Quinoa-Jimaca-Salad.jpg",
    "name": "Watermelon Quinoa Jicama Salad (\u003cspan style=\"color: lightblue;\"\u003eVE\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan style=\"color: goldenrod;\"\u003eGF\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan style=\"color: yellow;\"\u003eDF\u003c/span\u003e)",
    "objectId": "x1zpkWmvmP",
    "price": 14,
    "flavors": [{
      "active": false,
      "name": "Vanilla",
      "price": 8
    }, {
      "active": false,
      "name": "Almond",
      "price": 8
    }, {
      "active": false,
      "name": "Hazelnut",
      "price": 8
    }, {
      "active": false,
      "name": "Caramel",
      "price": 8
    }],
    "sizes": [{
      "active": false,
      "name": "Small",
      "price": 0
    }, {
      "active": false,
      "name": "Medium",
      "price": 5
    }, {
      "active": false,
      "name": "Large",
      "price": 10
    }],
    "sides": [{
      "active": false,
      "name": "Soup"
    }, {
      "active": false,
      "name": "Salad"
    }, {
      "active": false,
      "name": "Fries"
    }],
    "updatedAt": "2015-10-09T17:20:50.527Z"
  }, {
    "active": false,
    "createdAt": "2015-10-05T20:35:01.363Z",
    "desc": "Buffalo mozzarella, tomato, marinated artichoke hearts, black olives, pesto \u0026 balsamic drizzle",
    "img": "https://signsrestaurant.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Mediterranean-Salad.jpg",
    "name": "Mediterranean Salad (\u003cspan style=\"color: lightgreen;\"\u003eV\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan style=\"color: goldenrod;\"\u003eGF\u003c/span\u003e)",
    "objectId": "nI5VSpdBUn",
    "price": 15,
    "flavors": [{
      "active": false,
      "name": "Chocolate",
      "price": 8
    }, {
      "active": false,
      "name": "Strawberry",
      "price": 8
    }, {
      "active": false,
      "name": "Mint",
      "price": 8
    }, {
      "active": false,
      "name": "Cherry",
      "price": 8
    }],
    "sizes": [{
      "active": false,
      "name": "Small",
      "price": 5
    }, {
      "active": false,
      "name": "Medium",
      "price": 10
    }, {
      "active": false,
      "name": "Large",
      "price": 15
    }],
    "sides": [{
      "active": false,
      "name": "Soup"
    }, {
      "active": false,
      "name": "Salad"
    }, {
      "active": false,
      "name": "Fries"
    }],
    "updatedAt": "2015-10-09T17:20:30.545Z"
  }]
};
```

My relevant HTML in the Options page is below:

```
<md-list>
  <h2 class="md-title" style="color:#3F51B5;">Select Your Side</h2>
  <md-divider></md-divider>
  <md-list-item layout="row">
    <md-select aria-label="side set" class="md-accent" placeholder="Select a Side" ng-model="selecteds[name]">
      <md-option ng-value="item.name" ng-repeat="item in item.sides">{{ item.name }}</md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

My HTML in Order page is below:

```
  <md-list-item layout="row">
    <span>Side: {{selecteds}}</span>
  </md-list-item>
```

Here's a plunker to make sense out of it all. However, please note that my JS are all mixed in index.html (I apologize in advance).

http://plnkr.co/edit/4ByCDzXZfRU7kMX9oURT?p=preview

As you can see, when you press the purple button there for an item and select 'Soup' as a side, it displays as Side: {"undefined":"Soup"} in the Order page and I just need Side: Soup to be displayed.

The other major problem is that when 2 dishes are selected, the side selections are inter-linked, ie, if you select the first side, the second side is also selected and vice versa. So, if you select 'Soup' for the first item, Soup is selected for the second as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it figured out and have tweaked it to perfection. I created a new JSON data, additionally for adding an initial option for the dropdown so that the first selection is automatically selected. I used item.type as an element for this. Then, I used the following script:

```
  $scope.type = {};
  angular.forEach($scope.items, function(value) {
    $scope.type = value;
  });
```

After that, I modified the HTML to below:

```
<md-list>
  <h2 class="md-title" style="color:#3F51B5;">Select Your Side</h2>
  <md-divider></md-divider>
  <md-list-item layout="row">
    <md-select placeholder="Select a Side" ng-model="item.type">
      <md-option aria-label="side set" class="md-accent" ng-value="item.name" ng-repeat="item in item.sides">{{ item.name }}</md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/4ByCDzXZfRU7kMX9oURT?p=preview